# Duda con la función opendir() en PHP7

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, funciones, php7, localhost

estoy comenzado a aprender PHP y tenia unas cuántas dudas puntuales con respecto a la función opendir() y al valor que retorna al imprimirla despues de guardarla en una variable.
Me gustaria saber que significa el:
**Resource (3, stream)** Al imprimirlo con la función var_dump()
Y el **Resource id #3** Al imprimirlo con el echo y el porqué dicho id se empieza a númerar desde el 3.

```
<?php
// Abriendo el gestor del directorio con la función:
$carpeta = opendir('./carpeta');

var_dump($carpeta);
echo $carpeta;
```

Esto es lo que me genera dicha función despues de guardarla en una variable, imprimiendola con el var_dump y con el echo:

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y una última duda al recargar la página aún sin hacer niguna modificación en el código. El valor del id cambia a 2 ¿A qué se debe esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria todo el feedback que me pudieran dar, lo agradeceria mucho ya que me estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta función puede devolver:

- **false**: en caso de que ocurra algún error al momento de llamarla.
- **resource o recurso**: como indica la documentación de PHP es una variable "especial" con referencia a un recurso externo. Es un tipo de dato más de PHP (data type), como lo puede ser string, integer, float, etc.

Se puede resumir que un resource es una especie de puntero al recurso con el que estás trabajando.

Otro ejemplo podría ser cuando se trabaja con filehandle o manejo de ficheros sucede lo mismo, un ejemplo:

**Código**:

```
$handle_fichero = fopen("fichero_de_ejemplo.txt", "r");
var_dump($handle_fichero);
```

**Salida**:

```
resource(3) of type (stream)
```

También podemos saber si una variable es una referencia con la función `is_resource`:

**Código**:

```
var_dump(is_resource($handle_fichero));
```

**Salida**:

```
bool(true)
```

Esto será así con todos los tipos de recursos. Estos los podrás ver en la siguiente entrada a la documentación de PHP: [Lista de Recursos PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/resource.php)